# THREE.js: RingGeometry and CircleGeometry blurry when rotating the scene

Tags: three.js, mesh, geometry-shader

I'm using RingGeometry in my scene, at start the rings are renderer perfectly, but if I rotate the scene, artifacts appears on the rings.
I tried CircleGeometry and I have the same result.
The circle and the scene has an alpha channel because I need to variate the rings opacity.

[Before rotating a ring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrNEQ.png)

[After rotating a ring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf0o9.png)

[Before rotating a circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfvV9.png)

[After rotating a circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63NGO.png)

Comment: Looks like z-fighting. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting

Comment: I think it’s because you should add [minimal code to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can see where the problem is taking place. Otherwise the best we can do is guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Marquizzo that was it.
I have and invisible circle at the same position (used for raycaster.intersectObjects), even if it was at opacity 0 it was causing z-fighting.
I moved this invisible circle on the z-axis and the render is perfect now.